# Does ServerSocket create a new socket for each connection?

Tags: java, sockets, networking, serversocket

I read following statement in the [Socket tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/definition.html).

> If everything goes well, the server accepts the connection. **Upon
>   acceptance, the server gets a new socket bound to the same local port**
>   and also has its remote endpoint set to the address and port of the
>   client. **It needs a new socket so that it can continue to listen to the
>   original socket for connection requests while tending to the needs of
>   the connected client.**

Below are my questions:

1. Please correct my understanding from above - I open a socket (`ServerSocket`) by specifying a port, lets say 8001, now my server will start listening to requests on this port, now it gets a request from a client, something like `http://abc:8001/test`, so once it accepts the connection it will create a local port lets say 10001, so now this client request will be entertained over 10001 (or in other words connection with client would be established over port 10001) while 8001 will again be free and listening for new requests?
2. So, does it means that original port I specified with `ServerSocket` will never be used for establishing connections?
3. So, does it mean that if I having a connection with a client, let say over port 9001, then there can never be one more communication happening (or in other words connection established) on the same 9001 port until the original request I am catering is completed?

Please feel free to detailed light on the concepts of these questions, this will not only help me but also future visitors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Does `ServerSocket` create a new socket for every connection?

Yes.

> I open a socket (ServerSocket) by specifying a port, lets say 8001, now my server will start listening to requests on this port, now it gets a request from a client, something like http://abc:8001/test, so once it accepts the connection it will create a local port lets say 10001,

No.

> so now this client request will be entertained over 10001

No.

(or in other words connection with client would be established over port 10001)

No.

> while 8001 will again be free and listening for new requests?

Yes.

> So, does it means that original port I specified with ServerSocket will never be used for establishing connections?

No.

> So, does it mean that if I having a connection with a client, let say over port 9001, then there can never be one more communication happening (or in other words connection established) on the same 9001 port until the original request I am catering is completed?

No.

The accepted socket uses the same local port as the listening socket, exactly as per the text you quoted.

You are confusing new sockets, as per your title, with new ports, as per the body of your question.

Comment: Ok, so it means port is just a number which help TCP module to decide which application/process/service to send the request?

Comment: You said YES for my this question "*Does ServerSocket create a new socket for every connection?*", now if it is same port then it means it same socket, right? Because socket is nothing but combination of IP address and port? So, it mean it is always same socket at server side, but multiple connections are possible because there is a different client socket each time? I think I am now confused on "socket" because as I understood socket is combination of IP and port, and if server doesn't assign another local port, then how a "new socket"?

Comment: No, 'same port' doesn't mean 'same socket'. It means a new socket using the same local port, as I already said, and as it says in  the text that you quoted. How many times does this need to be stated?

Comment: Kindly do not answer without understanding the question, let me "state" my question again - if socket is a combination of IP and port, and server doesn't use another port number, then how this is statement is true that server will open a new socket for each connection?

Comment: The connection is identified by both endpoints, not just the local endpoint. Have a look at the discussion in the duplicate.

Comment: Ok, let's say my server have 5 open connections, in all these connections, my endpoint at server will always be same, i.e. if IP address is `142.23.24.2` and port is `7001` then for all 5 connections server endpoint will be `142.23.24.2:7001`, is it right? It is the client endpoint which makes a connection unique?

Comment: It is the combination of all four items. They call it the 4-tuple. This is all discussed in the duplicate.

Comment: Ok, I read Colin's answer in duplicate and he is saying same thing, `0.0.0.0:45000 -> 1.1.1.1:80` and `0.0.0.0:4500` -> 1.1.1.1:80`, so it means my understanding was right that server will always have same endpoint for all connections with client.